# How do you determine the default font size?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have some code which takes a template document and copies it into a new document for later text replacement. It essentially works, except that whenever the default font size is used in the template, `getFontSize()` returns a -1. When this is written to the output document, it is written as 32768.

My assumption is that `getFontSize()` returns a -1 to indicate that the default font size is not being overridden. So in my particular case I can do:

```
if(run.getFontSize() > 0) {
    newRun.setFontSize(run.getFontSize());
} else {
    newRun.setFontSize(12);
}
```

However, I'd like this code to work when the default font size is not 12. How can I do this? Or is the default font size *always* 12?

Comment: which class in apache poi does `getFontSize()` belong to?

Comment: `XWPFRun.getFontSize()`